# Kotlin - keeping a list of properties without repeating class name

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I keep a list of the names for **a subset** of the properties in class. Example:

```
listOf(
  Car::model.name,
  Car::make.name,
  Car::company.name,
  Car::year.name,
  Car::power.name,
  Car::cylinders.name,
  Car::gearType.name,
  Car::seats.name,
)
```

This can be shortened as follows, so that `Car` and `.name` are not repeated per list element.

```
with (Car()) {
  listOf(
    ::model,
    ::make,
    ::company,
    ::year,
    ::power,
    ::cylinders,
    ::gearType,
    ::seats,
  )
}.map { it.name }
```

I don't like this approach though, because it creates an object from the class. This may not be possible in all situations (private constructors, non-default constructor with many dependencies, or the object may be expensive to construct).

Is there a better solution?

Comment: What will you be using this list for? (I can't think of a case where it would be useful, where there isn't a better approach.)

Comment: @gidds For monitoring changed to specific field of interest in a JPA entity using Hibernate event listerners.

Answer (score -2):

You need to check why the `it.name` is needed. You're using a reflectional way to get the name of all/some fields. First of all you're having a reflective property element in your hands and then you just want to get the properties name.

If you want to shorten the mapping (+1 iteration) you can simply add `.name` already in the `listOf()` part.

Please notice that this is a very static way. If you want to have all fields OR/and properties you can use this as well:

```
Car::class.members // Members and Fields are different!!
```

Or you access the generated java class fields: `Car::class.java.declaredFields` and map it to list.

Shortest example for everything: Car::class.java.declaredFields.map{ it.name }

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work. If you look at the question, I've written **a subset** of the properties in bold just to prevent this answer: I'm not interested in all properties; rather, a few of them that I know by name. Also, iterating over such a short list isn't important as it's done only once.

Comment: So just add `.name` to your code above and remote the mapping part